# How to use re expression python

Tags: python, regex

I want to use `(+-/)\1+` which you can see on https://regex101.com/r/KhUoyy/1. I am using it on a calculator program so the user can't spam + or - or / but I don't know how to use it. I have tried using it in `re.sub("(+-/)\1+",string)` but it needs 3 parameters and I also have tried `re.sub("(.)\1+","",x)`. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I think you want to substitute with the capturing group `result = re.sub(r"(.)\1+", r'\1', "a++2==2")` https://ideone.com/wkfx71

Comment: @Thefourthbird how can I use it to only filter out + - /?

Comment: In that case you could make use of a character class `re.sub(r"([+/?-])\1+", r'\1', "a++2==2")`

Comment: @Thefourthbird that solved my problem thank you for your help